# using Object.values() method to assign a constant array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants, mutating-function

How would I fill const objArray with numObj object's values using the Object.values() method? I've only been able to do it with a for loop + push method (demonstrated below)

```
const numObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objArray = [];

for (var values in numObj) {
  objArray.push(numObj[values]);
  }
```

Comment: `Object.values()` returns the array you want

Answer (score 2):

```
 objArray.push(...Object.values(numObj));
```

Or you directly assign it:

```
const objArray = Object.values(numObj));
```

Comment: i've tried directly assigning it with:
    `const objArray = Object.values(numObj));`
but it gives me an error says objArray has already been declared.

However -- this works!
    `objArray.push(...Object.values(numObj));`

what is the "..." because without it, it's an array with in array [[1, 2, 5, 18]]

Comment: @needto thats the spread operator. And if you take the second approach, remove the `const objArray = []`

Answer (score 0):

You could use spread syntax with `push` method.

```js
const numObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objArray = [];
objArray.push(...Object.values(numObj));
console.log(objArray)
```